# Reportlab error after deploying

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reportlab

I have an app running on GAE, using reportlab to email generated PDF's.
When I run my reportlab app on localhost everything works perfectly.  But when I run it after deploying, it throws out an error.

**Error**

> IOError: Cannot open resource
>   "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.375717494064852868/static/img/__.jpg"

**Line**

> img=[
>       [Image(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)),
>        'static/img/__.jpg'))]
>       ]

**app.yaml**

> -url: /static/img
>     static_dir: static/img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access files from your application code that are covered by a static-file route in your app config, you need to set `application_readable` to `true`. Or, you can move/copy the file somewhere else in your project.